# pass ActionLink parameters to perform GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to perform a GET and pass parameters using Ajax.ActionLink

`<%= Ajax.ActionLink("12", "ActionMethod", new { id = 1}` ...

Currently, the line above performs a POST.

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("12", "ActionMethod", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" })%>
```